# tomcat doesn't work properly, alfresco 4 won't start

Tags: tomcat, alfresco

i've a serious problem!i've installed Alfresco 4.2.c on Win 7 OS 64bit - Java installed: jdk 1.7.0_17 .
I suppose it's a problem about configuration and not alfresco itself. 
So i run tomcat and Postgres from manager-windows then i type localhost:8081 in firefox and i see the Tomcat home page. OK!
But, and it's really strange, if i type localhost:8081/alfresco i receive the error: HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco

This is the log of Alfresco\tomcat\log\alfrescotomcat-stderr:

```
2013-04-13 14:30:44 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized

apr 13, 2013 2:30:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.24 using APR version 1.4.6.

apr 13, 2013 2:30:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].

apr 13, 2013 2:30:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL

INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012)

apr 13, 2013 2:30:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]

apr 13, 2013 2:30:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

apr 13, 2013 2:30:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]

apr 13, 2013 2:30:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 3122 ms

apr 13, 2013 2:30:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

apr 13, 2013 2:30:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30

apr 13, 2013 2:30:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Alfresco\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr.xml

apr 13, 2013 2:30:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin

WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.

apr 13, 2013 2:31:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco.war

apr 13, 2013 2:31:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener

INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.

apr 13, 2013 2:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal

SEVERE: Error listenerStart

apr 13, 2013 2:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal

SEVERE: Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors

apr 13, 2013 2:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

SEVERE: The web application [/alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@13e7b625]) and a value of type [org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.NamespaceDAOImpl.NamespaceRegistry] (value [org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.NamespaceDAOImpl$NamespaceRegistry@51674158]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

apr 13, 2013 2:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

SEVERE: The web application [/alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@51f32228]) and a value of type [org.alfresco.util.CachingDateFormat] (value [yyyy-MM-dd]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

apr 13, 2013 2:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

SEVERE: The web application [/alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@7a8ec5ca]) and a value of type [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.RecordValue=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@4fea5230, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.DataExtractors=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@20b9f64d, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.DataExtractor=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@10d94a04, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.PathMappings=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@298a5540, class javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@38e2f20e, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.Audit=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@3b81924f, class java.util.ArrayList=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@37ac9f0e, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.DataGenerator=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@25fe6cb0, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.GenerateValue=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@6291aa4c, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.AuditPath=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@49439622, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.DataGenerators=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@7435b7c1, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.PathMap=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@72b31b81, class org.alfresco.repo.audit.model._3.Application=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@4cd2ecfb}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

apr 13, 2013 2:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

SEVERE: The web application [/alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@7b7ca93d]) and a value of type [org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl] (value [org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl@354b2321]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

apr 13, 2013 2:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

SEVERE: The web application [/alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1] (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1@57ef66dc]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@264a229e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

apr 13, 2013 2:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share.war

apr 13, 2013 2:33:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\host-manager

apr 13, 2013 2:33:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\manager

apr 13, 2013 2:33:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\ROOT

apr 13, 2013 2:33:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]

apr 13, 2013 2:33:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

apr 13, 2013 2:33:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]

apr 13, 2013 2:33:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 144182 ms

apr 13, 2013 2:33:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass

INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.AES$ECB.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

java.lang.IllegalStateException

    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)

    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1279)

    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1237)

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:845)

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1348)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:175)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:208)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:467)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:507)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:485)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:190)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:342)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:293)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:576)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:494)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:313)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.acceptSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:182)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:216)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)



apr 13, 2013 2:33:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass

INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.AES$ECB.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

java.lang.IllegalStateException

    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)

    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1279)

    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1237)

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:845)

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1348)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:175)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:208)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:467)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:507)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:485)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:190)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:342)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:293)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:576)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:494)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:313)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.acceptSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:182)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:216)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)



apr 13, 2013 2:33:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass

INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.AES$ECB.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

java.lang.IllegalStateException

    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)

    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1279)

    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1237)

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:845)

    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1348)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(CipherBox.java:175)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(CipherBox.java:208)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(CipherSuite.java:467)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:507)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:485)

    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:190)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:342)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:293)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:576)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:494)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:313)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.acceptSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:182)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:216)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)



ry.java:222)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)

    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)

    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)

    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)

    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use

    at sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable.putTarget(ObjectTable.java:186)

    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.exportObject(Transport.java:92)

    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:247)

    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)

    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)

    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:207)

    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:122)

    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:98)

    at java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(LocateRegistry.java:239)

    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.getRegistry(RmiServiceExporter.java:371)

    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.getRegistry(RmiServiceExporter.java:336)

    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.prepare(RmiServiceExporter.java:268)

    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.afterPropertiesSet(RmiServiceExporter.java:229)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)

    ... 27 more



apr 13, 2013 2:32:23 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized

INFO: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing

apr 13, 2013 2:32:27 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>

INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing

apr 13, 2013 2:32:27 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate destroy

INFO: WSSERVLET15: JAX-WS servlet destroyed

apr 13, 2013 2:32:27 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed

INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed

apr 13, 2013 2:32:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

apr 13, 2013 2:32:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

INFO: Shutting down log4j
```

Comment: What's in your alfresco.log file? That should hopefully explain why you're getting `SEVERE: Error listenerStart` which is the key line

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is problem with the bouncy castle jars in alfresco.
It looks like the bcprov-jdk.jar which is there within alfreco is conflicting with the jdk which you are using.
Check out the compatible version for that

Comment: not this the problem...i've checked the compatibility page of bouncy castle and then change to jdk-1.5 but the problem remain the same...

Comment: Hi i've solved the issue!
i just modify the hosts file with:  127.0.0.1       pcName     localhost

and now it works!!!